# Objects are not valid as React child error when debug remote is disabled?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm facing this issue on my react native app for the past couple of days. Now I'm really frustrated and don't know how to solve this error. Whenever I run the app by react-native run-android command and app crash on startup with given error but when I enable remote debug then app does not crash. Please help me on this one.
Thanks

[Please visit here to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx9fF.png)

Comment: Your error clearly state that, you are trying to render object. The object contains $$typeof, type, key ... etc. So you need to check from where you are getting this object.

Comment: app works fine when debug mode is enabled so I don't understand from where this error is occurring

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the error by importing firebase as:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```